# Prevent multiple instances of a page in TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I am making an application where i am opening wpf pages in tab control. But i am able to open same page again and again in tabcontrol. I want that if once page is opened it can't be opened again and it should get focused on tabcontrol if i try to open it again. i did following code but not working. I am using a custom closableTabItem Usercontrol.

```
private void Set_Fee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Adding page to frame and then adding that frame to tab item and then adding tab item to main tab.
    FeeStructure feePage = new FeeStructure();
    _closableTab = new ClosableTabItem();
    _formFrame = new Frame();
    _formFrame.Content = feePage;
    _closableTab.Content = _formFrame;
    _closableTab.Header = "Set Fee Structure";

    if (!mainTab.Items.Contains(_closableTab))
    {
        mainTab.Items.Add(_closableTab);
        _closableTab.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        _closableTab.Focus();
    }
}

private void Database_RecoveryBackup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Adding page to frame and then adding that frame to tab item and then adding tab item to main tab.
    DbRecoveryBackup dbRecBack = new DbRecoveryBackup();
    _closableTab = new ClosableTabItem();
    _formFrame = new Frame();
    _formFrame.Content = dbRecBack;
    _closableTab.Content = _formFrame;
    _closableTab.Header = "Data Base";

    if (!mainTab.Items.Contains(_closableTab))
    {
        mainTab.Items.Add(_closableTab);
        _closableTab.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        _closableTab.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll never happen, what you want because you're creating a new instance of `ClosableTabItem` everytime, hence it is unique everytime, so `.Items.Contains` will never work in this case because it matches items using `object.Equals`.

Now, Since you said in question that you only want one instance of `ClosableTabItem`, then
using Linq, you can check if in the items there exist any item of type `ClosableTabItem`,

```
...
// Here we're checking the array 'Items',
// if it contains any item whose type is 'ClosableTabItem'
if (!mainTab.Items.Any(item => item is ClosableTabItem)))    
...
```

Comment: `f is ClosableTabItem` will work much faster. or `Items.OfType<ClosableTabItem>().Any()`